# Play! 2.0.2 and Mailer module

Tags: module, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use [mailer module](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) for Play! 2.0.3/Scala.

1) updating `Build.scala` didn't help to make the classes availble - do I need to `play clean`? I ended up brutally dropping a jar into `lib`.

2) more puzzling, what is the `use[]` method in the tutorial? (`use[MailerPlugin].email`)? I never saw it in the imports, neither it is in tutorial's imports.

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "some-some"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
        "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}
```

Comment: Please show your `Build.scala` file.

Answer (score 0):

1) That was an issue in IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) only.

In order for it to pick up Build.scala dependencies, run `play dependencies` and `play idea`. The new project will include the Maven dependencies.

2) I should have been more attentive.

The compiler error itself says "add import play.api.Play.current", which does solve the problem.

Comment: did you, "import com.typesafe.plugin._" prior to "use[..."?

Comment: Hey @Victor, did you solve your 1st question? My app doesn't compile in the IDE without manually adding the JAR. Compiles "in the browser" though..

Comment: IDEA doesn't support Build.scala for now (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4600#comment=27-370420) Expecting soon, though. And re-generating project files helps.
I'll update my answer with my comment at that bug.